# Opening an sqlite database stored in NSData object "in memory"

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdata

Is it possible to open an sqlite database stored in an NSData object?

Ex:

```
NSData *sqliteDb = [self fetchDb];
```

can I open this DB using the in memory functionality of sqlite3 - `sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);`